# Tailwind css not working properly, need to reload. Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css

i am coding an app with tailwind involved. I've changes the styles of Devises views with tailwind classes.

When I go to the Log In page, most of tailwing css is taking effect, exept a button which is supposed to be orange but is white and input focus which are supposed to be orange but are blue.

When i go to previous page, the problem is deported to this previous page. (which was fine before).

When i refresh the page it works fine and there is no problem anymore.

Does this pb rings a bell ?

Thank you and have a good day.